# Conocer si un 'id' existe en un ArrayList de objetos de forma optima

Tags: java, optimización, collection

Estoy intentando saber si mi objeto Carta tiene un id (que no tiene porque coincidir con el indice de la colección de objetos cartas). Mi solución actual es recorrer toda la colección e ir comparando una a una todos los id.

Esto es valido si la cantidad de objetos es relativamente pequeña. Pero, ¿si tuviera 100.000 objetos seria poco optimo?

Estoy estudiando y esta es una duda que me ha surgido. No es una posibilidad usar una base de datos aun.

Aquí os voy a presentar la clase Carta.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Carta {
    private int id;
    private String nombre;
    private String comentario;
    private String efecto;
    private Tipo tipo;
    private Ilustracion ilustracion;
    private List<Ampliacion> ampliaciones;
    
    public Carta(int id, String nombre, String comentario, String efecto, Tipo tipo, Ilustracion ilustracion, List<Ampliacion> ampliaciones) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.comentario = comentario;
        this.efecto = efecto;
        this.tipo = tipo;
        this.ilustracion = ilustracion;
        this.ampliaciones = ampliaciones;
    }

    public Carta(int id, String nombre, Tipo tipo, Ilustracion ilustracion, List<Ampliacion> ampliaciones) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.tipo = tipo;
        this.ilustracion = ilustracion;
        this.ampliaciones = ampliaciones;
    }
    
    public Carta(int id, String nombre) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        ampliaciones = new ArrayList<Ampliacion>();

    }

    public Carta() {
        super();
        ampliaciones = new ArrayList<Ampliacion>();
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getComentario() {
        return comentario;
    }

    public void setComentario(String comentario) {
        this.comentario = comentario;
    }

    public String getEfecto() {
        return efecto;
    }

    public void setEfecto(String efecto) {
        this.efecto = efecto;
    }

    public Tipo getTipo() {
        Tipo t;
        if (tipo != null) {
            t = new Tipo(tipo.getId(), tipo.getNombre());
        } else {
            t = null;
        }
        return t;
    }

    public void setTipo(Tipo tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    public Ilustracion getIlustracion() {
        Ilustracion i;
        if (ilustracion != null)
             i = new Ilustracion(this.ilustracion.getId(), this.ilustracion.getAutor());
        else
            i = null;
        return i;
    }

    public void setIlustracion(Ilustracion ilustracion) {
        this.ilustracion = ilustracion;
    }

    public List<Ampliacion> getAmpliaciones() {
        List<Ampliacion> amplAux = new ArrayList<Ampliacion>();
        for (Ampliacion a: ampliaciones) {
            amplAux.add(new Ampliacion(a.getId(), a.getNombre(), a.getSiglas()));
        }
        
        return amplAux;
    }

    public void setAmpliaciones(List<Ampliacion> ampliaciones) {
        this.ampliaciones = ampliaciones;
    }
    
    public void addAmpliacion(Ampliacion ampliacion) {
        this.ampliaciones.add(ampliacion);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + id;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Carta other = (Carta) obj;
        if (id != other.id)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

Ahora os voy a presentar mi solución actual a este problema en especifico:

```
    public Carta obtenerCartaDesdeId(int id, List<Carta> cartas) {
        Carta cartaDevolver = null;
        for (Carta carta: cartas) {
            if (carta.getId() == id) {
                cartaDevolver = carta;
            }
        }
        
        return cartaDevolver;
    }
```

La cuestión es: Usando Java 14, **¿Es esta la forma mas optima de saber si existe un id dentro de una colección de objetos?** Teniendo en cuenta que el id no tiene por que coincidir con el indice de la propia colección. **Si existe una forma mas optima, ¿Cuando y como se puede aplicar?**

Gracias y un saludo.

Comment: Sin duda no. Si crees que vas a tener tantos objetos, al menos haz que el for termine cuando lo encuentre y no siga buscando hasta terminar con el último elemento del array.

Comment: Si el arraylist estuviese ordenado podrías usar una búsqueda binaria que es muchísimo más rápida que la búsqueda secuencial que usas, pero el inconveniente es precisamente que el arreglo debe estar ordenado. Te sugiero que investigues sobre búsqueda binaria y otros tipos de búsqueda sobre arreglos en internet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar un filter el cual está disponible a partir de java 8 para streams.

1. Conviertes tu array a stream con `.stream()`.
2. Aplicas un filter cuando `carta.getId()` es igual al id.
3. Usar `findAny()` para encontrar solamente uno.
4. Usar `orElse(null)` para devolver un valor por defecto en caso de que no se encuentre ninguna coincidencia.

Aquí el código resultante.

```
    cartas.stream()
      .filter(carta-> carta.getId() == id)
      .findAny()
      .orElse(null);
```

Si se prevee un número alto de objetos en la lista, podría ser útil emplear un `parallelStream`:

```
    cartas.parallelStream()
      .filter(carta-> carta.getId() == id)
      .findAny()
      .orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

si las id's de las cartas no se repetiran dentro del mismo array, podrias utilizar HashMap en su lugar

un HashMap lo declaras asi

```
HashMap<int, Carta> arrayCartas = new HashMap<int, Carta>();
```

tu metodo obtenerCartaDesdeId quedaria asi

```
public Carta obtenerCartaDesdeId(int id, HashMap<int, Carta> cartas) {
   // el método get() devuelve null si no se encontró la llave 
   // especificada
   return cartas.get(id);
}
```

Atencion: si lo haces asi la clase Carta ya no necesitaria una variable id, esta (variable id) seria manejada por el objeto HashMap que la contenga, ten en cuenta eso porque si el resto del programa necesita que la propia carta tenga definida dentro de si su id esta solucion ya no te servira